# Unable to map docker port from vite app to local

Tags: reactjs, typescript, docker, vite

I am trying to dockerize a scratch vite react ts app.

```
FROM node:15.12.0

WORKDIR /app

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

ADD . .

RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

Docker compose:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  dev:
    build: 
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
```

I am starting it using docker up --build
App seems to be started and ported because docker ps shows:
f5e840a7fec3   leoapp/leo   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   sad_gates

But I am unable to access port 3000 on my browser. What am I doing wrong here.
Vite uses esbuild internally. We need to rebuild esbuild for container architecture during the startup to make it function without errors.

```
Contents of: entrypoint.sh

#!/bin/sh

npm rebuild esbuild

exec "$@"
Dockerfile

# ...

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

# ...
```

When I access port 3000 I get this site cant be reached, however I am able to run the app if run normally i.e `npm run dev`

Comment: What goes wrong?  What's actually in the `entrypoint.sh` script?  Are you trying to connect to some URL and getting some error?

Comment: cannt conect to website from my browser. The entrypoint.sh is here https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2671#issuecomment-829535806

Comment: Please edit the question to include all of the required details in the question itself.  I can't tell what URL you're trying to get to, what error you're getting, or what the main container process is.  Based on what you've shown, port 3000 on the host should forward to port 3000 in the container, but that still leaves a pretty broad space of potential issues.

Comment: @DavidMaze I have updated the question. I have added the contents of entrypoint shell file too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your vite.config file you need to set `host: true`.
So, your file should look similar to this:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    watch: {
      usePolling: true,
    },
    host: true, // needed for the Docker Container port mapping to work
    strictPort: true,
    port: 3000, // replace this port with any number you want
  }, 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your ost publicly available in vite.confi.ts

This worked for me.

```js
export default defineConfig({
     plugins: [react()],
     server: {
      host: "0.0.0.0",  // publicly available
      port: 5173
     },
    });
```